# What errors did I make in this very simple program on SharpDevelop?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sharpdevelop

I'm only a beginner, I've made a very simple program on SharpDevelop (C#), but it doesn't work.

Here it is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float pi;
    int n;
    pi=1;

    for(n=1; n<1000; n++)
    {
        pi=pi+((-1)^n)/(2*n+1);

        Console.WriteLine(""+pi);
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

It should just calculate pi, but it only returns a lot of 1s instead... SharpDevelop doesn't report any "error".

Could somebody point out what errors I made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using an integer arithmetic, so each time your expression `((-1)^n)/(2*n+1)` is rounded to `0`.
Try to replace your `pi` calculation with the following line:

```
pi += (float)Math.Pow(-1f, n) / (2*n+1);
```

By the way, the `^` operator is not the exponentiation.